# ZSH automatically run commands after selecting FZF result

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, fzf

I'm using ZSH and am trying to integrate FZF into my config. It all works fine now, the only thing bothering me is that after searching for the command I want to run in FZF (e.g. a file/directory name) and pressing `<ENTER>` to close FZF, I have to press `<ENTER>` again to run the command.

Is there a way to run the command automatically after selecting an FZF result?

EDIT:
Thanks to @svlasov I now have this solution:

```
export FZF_COMPLETION_TRIGGER=""
setopt vi # Removes the default FZF '<TAB>' keybinding

fzf-and-run-widget() {
    fzf-completion
    zle accept-line
}
zle -N         fzf-and-run-widget
bindkey '^[^I' fzf-and-run-widget
```

Comment: Depends on what "run" means to you. For simple shellscript execution (like `./myscript.sh`), you could prepend `./` to the chosen file and have fzf on pressing Enter replace itself with that command using `become`, e.g. as `fzf --bind "enter:become(./{})"`. Adapt ths to `xdg-open` or whatever you consider "running" your chosen item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to `.zshrc`:

```
fzf-and-run-widget() {
  fzf-history-widget
  zle accept-line
}
zle     -N   fzf-and-run-widget
bindkey '^R' fzf-and-run-widget
```

- `fzf-history-widget` is part of fzf distribution, defined in `key-bindings.zsh`. Replace with your own, if needed.
- `zle accept-line` executes whatever is currently in ZSH prompt.
- `'^R'` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>. Change to something else, if needed.

Comment: Thanks that looks like what I was searching for!
Do you know which widget I would use to get the "normal" fzf completion? (I mean the one triggered by typing `**<TAB>`)

Comment: It must be `fzf-file-widget`.

Comment: I already tried that one, but it only does files. I mean the one that adjusts to the command typed (for example, when I type `ssh **<TAB>` it gives me a list of hostnames to choose from)

Comment: Try `fzf-completion`.

Comment: That just gives me the completion I would get without fzf, although because of the `accept-line` statement, the command is automatically executed without any completion.
Anyways, I think I'll open a new Question for that, thanks for your help :D

Comment: Did you remember to bind it to `^I`?

Comment: I fixed it; the problem was that `fzf-completion` still checks for the trigger (i.e. '**') in the console. As I didn't have a blank String as the Trigger, it was automatically quitting as it didn't find that. I added my resulting snippet to the original Post. Thanks again!